# mongoose unable to find refs using $in operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user schema like this

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  following: [{created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}, target: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true }}]
});
```

And a user activity schema:

```
var activity = new mongoose.Schema({
   text: String,
   private: Boolean,
   _creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true }
});
```

I'm trying to get all the activites where the `_creator` is `$in` the `following` sub-document of the user.

```
userModel.methods.getNewsfeed = function(callback){
  var following_targets = _.pluck(this.following, 'target') // using underscore.js
  activityModel.find(
  {
            $or: [
                {
                    _creator: this._id
                }
                ,
                {
                    $and: [
                        { private: { $ne: true } }
                    ,   {'_creator': { $in: following_targets }}
                    ]
                }
            ]

        }
  )
  .exec(callback);
}
```

However this query only returns activites created by the current user. Removing the `_creator: this._id` part returns an empty array.

Comment: What does the query look like that returns you what you want in the mongo shell? You can then tell mongoose to use debug mode so you can see the queries it is running and then compare them and update as required.

Comment: @AlistairNelson I found what I did wrong, see my answer. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was wrong.
I manually inserted sample user documents using the mongo shell, the `target` in the `following` array was a `String` instead of `ObjectId`, so mongoose could not find it.